Looking for fresh ideas: Cloudflare gives 502 error, but only on homepage, only in Chrome & only on desktop
I have been trying to debug this for a few days, appreciate any ideas at all. This is Wordpress on Debian 10 with nginx.
Cloudflare gives 502 error, but only on homepage, only in Chrome, but not in Incognito Chrome, but deleting cookies does not solve it. Also, in Chrome on phones no error.
Not sure if the issue is with my Chrome or on Cloudflare (such as with security settings being not configured well).
I tried:

disabling chrome plugins (no change)
clearing cache/browsing data (no change)
updating browser to latest version (no change)
checking DNS (no issue found)
disabling cache “development mode” (no change)
loosening security rules, disabling browser integrity check (no change)
tightening security rules because at this point i am just trying things at random (no change)

